# why is my accumulator not incrementing and always returuns zero?

Tags: java

I have just started to learn java so my question might be funny to most of you,
i am trying to write a program that calculate an average for an array of courses
and for some reason my accumulator is not incrementing

```
public void setStudents() {
    
        accumulator=0;
        
    for(int x=0;x<course.length;x++)
    {
         accumulator =accumulator+ course[x].result;
        
    }
}
public double getAverage () {
   average=(double)(accumulator/course.length);
    return average;
}
public int getTotal() {
    return accumulator;
}
```

Comment: The problem is outside the shown code. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: where is the course array declared and initiated?

Comment: Do you ever call `setStudents()`? What is `course.length`? Need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is wrapped in a class with a member field variable called `accumulator`. In this case, when the class is constructed, the `setStudents` method should be called, so that the accumulator is properly set. If you don't call the `setStudents` method in the constructor, or anywhere before you call the `getAverage` method, the `accumulator` field will just be set to its default value, which is 0. This is probably the reason why you are getting 0 as the result. This can be fixed by calling `setStudents` in the constructor of this class, or anywhere before you call the `getAverage` method. Also, in the `getAverage` method, you should be casting to double before doing the arithmetic, or else the integer division still gets called and then gets cast to a double afterward. So the line

```
average=(double)(accumulator/course.length);
```

should be

```
average=(double)(accumulator)/course.length;
```

Comment: yes you were right it worked tnx and also another question about the casting what is the problem with the 1st one could you explain to me a little bit more plz

Comment: The problem with the first cast is that you are doing the operation on the two ints first, so it does integer arithmetic first, and only then casts to double. This causes truncation because when the two ints are operated on, the quotient's decimal part is truncated off, so you want to cast to double first so that you get double and integer arithmetic(which does not have truncation).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Mine {
    int accumulator;
    double average;
    Course[] course = {Course.builder().result(10).build(), Course.builder().result(20).build(), Course.builder().result(30).build()};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mine obj=new Mine();
        obj.setStudents();
        double avg = obj.getAverage();
        System.out.println(avg);
    }

    public void setStudents() {
        Course[] course = {Course.builder().result(10).build(), Course.builder().result(20).build(), Course.builder().result(30).build()};
        for (int x = 0; x < course.length; x++) {
            accumulator = accumulator + course[x].result;
        }
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        average = (double) (accumulator / course.length);
        return average;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return accumulator;
    }
}

@Builder
@Data
class Course {
    int result;
}
```

If you see above code, i had just modified your existing code.

You made some minor mistake with  getting and assigning local variables.

Just go through with this [**`link`**](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/global-and-local-variables/), which will guide you about **`scope,global variable, local variables`**

Comment: `average = (double) (accumulator / course.length);` casting is not correct